# How to get an all sticky grid of Treeview and Scrollbar in Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, treeview

What I want in Tkinter in Python 2.7 is the following grid layout:

[image: Grid Layout]

However once, I start using the `grid()` functions instead of `pack()` functions, nothing is showing on running the script. The following is what I am stuck with:

```
import Tkinter, ttk

class App(Tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent, relief=Tkinter.SUNKEN, bd=2)
        self.parent = parent        
        self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.menubar = Tkinter.Menu(self)
        try:
            self.parent.config(menu=self.menubar)
        except AttributeError:
            self.tk.call(self.parent, "config", "-menu", self.menubar)    

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.parent)
        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.yscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self.tree.yview)
        self.yscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nse')
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=self.yscrollbar.set)
        self.yscrollbar.configure(command=self.tree.yview)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.title("MyApp")
    app = App(root)
    app.pack()
    app.mainloop()
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have several problems that are affecting your layout.

First, some of the widgets inside `App` use `self` as the parent, some use `self.parent`. They should all use `self` in this particular case. So, the first thing to do is change the parent option of the `Treeview` to `self`.

```
self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self)
```

Second, since your main code is calling `app.pack()`, you shouldn't be calling `self.grid`. Remove the line `self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew"). It's redundant.

Third, you are using very unusual code to add the menubar. You need to configure the menu of the root window. There's no need to put this in a `try/except` block, and there's no reason to use `self.tk.call`. Simply do this:

```
self.parent.configure(menu=self.menubar)
```

This assumes that `self.parent` is indeed the root window. If you don't want to force that assumption you can use `winfo_toplevel()` which will always return the top-most window:

```
self.parent.winfo_toplevel().configure(menu=self.menubar)
```

Finally, since you are using `grid`, you need to give at least one row and one column a "weight" so tkinter knows how to allocate extra space (such as when the user resizes a window).

In your case you want to give all of the weight to row and column 0 (zero), since that's where you've placed the widget which needs the most space:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    ...
    self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Note: you'll also want to make sure when you call `app.pack()` that you give it parameters that makes it fill any extra space, too. Otherwise the tree will fill "app", but "app" would not fill the window.

```
app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Here is a fully working example with all of those changes. I grouped the main layout code together since that makes the code easier to visualize and easier to maintain:

```
import Tkinter, ttk

class App(Tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent, relief=Tkinter.SUNKEN, bd=2)
        self.parent = parent        

        self.menubar = Tkinter.Menu(self)
        self.parent.winfo_toplevel().configure(menu=self.menubar)

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self)

        self.yscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self.tree.yview)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=self.yscrollbar.set)

        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.yscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nse')
        self.yscrollbar.configure(command=self.tree.yview)

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.title("MyApp")
    app = App(root)
    app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    app.mainloop()
```

---

Your question mentioned grid, but in this case you could save a few lines of code by using `pack`. `pack` excels in layouts like this, where your gui is aligned top-to-bottom and/or left-to-right. All you need to do is replace the last five lines (the calls to `grid`, grid_rowconfigure`and`grid_columnconfigure`) with these two lines:

```
self.yscrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
self.tree.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
```

Comment: Excellent! I see that the scrollbar crosses the floor level of the menubar upto the top of the window area. Can that be fixed?

Comment: @smlq: That's not what you're seeing. The menubar is invisible because you haven't put anything in it. What you think is the menubar is actually the header of the treeview. The menubar will always extend the full width of the window.

Comment: Oops! My mistake! Thanks! Heh heh! In fact I am using `pack()` only. It's cleaner in this particular layout.